# What precisely is the definition of connectedness?

Tags: general-topology

The definition of connectedness that I've been given is as follows:

> A topological space $(X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ is called connected if there do not exist two open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U,V\neq\emptyset$, $U\cap V=\emptyset$ and $U\cup V=X$. Similarly, $(X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ is called disconnected if $(X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ is not connected.

I'm asking the following merely in the name of clarification: when $U$ and $V$ are referred to as open sets here, does this mean that $U,V\in\mathcal{T}_X$, or does this simply mean that $U$ and $V$ are open sets in some arbitrary topology (or topologies, rather)?

Thank you in advance to any responses.

Comment: It means $U,V \in \mathcal T_X$.

Comment: Okay, so, given this fact, the topology $\lbrace\emptyset,[1/2,1)\cup(2,3/2],(0,1)\cup(2,3)\rbrace$ on $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ is connected, as per the definition of connectedness. Is this correct, or am I somehow misapplying the definition here? @azif00

Comment: Apologies, you are correct, I meant to add this to the definition in question. I've done so now. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt: Yes, that example is correct.

Comment: For the example: if you have an arbitrary set $X$ with an arbitrary subset $A$ of $X$, then $\{\emptyset,A,X\}$ is a topology on $X$ and with that topology, $X$ is connected.